# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable i think if statement error

Tags: python

```
def main():
series = input('Enter series of lowercase letters:')
index = 0
vowels = 0
constants = 0
while index < len(series):
    if series[index] in "aeiou":
        vowels += 1
        index += 1
    else:
        constants += 1
index += 1
print('Vowels:', vowels)
print('Constants:', constants)
main()
```

Ok so that fixed the error, but it just gives blank space for the answer why is it not counting them

Answer (score 1):

There are five things here:

1. You need to use square brackets `[...]` for indexing strings.
2. Your if-statement is always going to return `True` because non-empty strings evaluate to `True` in Python.
3. This isn't an error, but doing `var = var + n` is the same as `var += n`.
4. You misspelled "consonants". :)
5. You need to indent the last `index = index + 1` and remove the one before it.

Therefore, your code should be this:

```
def main():
    series = input('Enter series of lowercase letters:')
    index = 0
    vowels = 0
    consonants = 0
    while index < len(series):
        # Test if series[index] is in the string "aeiou"
        if series[index] in "aeiou":
            vowels += 1
        else:
            consonants += 1
        index += 1
    print('Vowels:', vowels)
    print('Constants:', consonants)
```

---

Also, just for future reference, your current if-statement is being read by Python like this:

```
if (series(index) == "a") or ("e") or ("i") or ("o") or ("u"):
```

Comment: You've missed the third error - the second `index += 1` should be _inside_ of the while loop, and the one inside the `if` should be removed. The current code will hang on the first consonant encountered. Oh and "constants" is a nice typo as well, I think OP meant "consonants"...

Comment: y does it hang on first consonant and how do i fix it

Comment: @user2976963 - Huh.  I don't know.  It runs fine on my system.  Maybe your computer glitched?

Comment: does it count the first consonant or is it 1 off. cuz "add" is giving me 1 vowel and 1 consonant

Comment: @user2976963 - No, that works for me too.  I believe you when you say you are seeing this behavior, but I don't know why it is.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `()` instead of `[]` for indexing:

```
series(index)
```

---

Secondly this is also incorrect:

```
if series(index) == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
```

as it is equivalent to:

```
if (series(index) == "a") or ("e") or ("i") or ("o") or ("u"):
```

So, even after using `series[index]` the `if` condition is always going to be True as a non-empty string(`"e"`) is always `True`:

Use this instead:

```
if series[index] in ("a" ,"e", "i", "o", "u"):
```

---

Lastly strings are iterable in python, so need to use a `while` loop and indexing:

```
def main():
    series = input('Enter series of lowercase letters:')
    vowels = 0
    constants = 0
    vowels = ("a" ,"e", "i", "o", "u")
    for c in series:
        if c in vowels:
            vowels = vowels + 1
        else:
            constants = constants + 1
```